# Attach to torquebox logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jboss, torquebox

How do I re-use the existing Torquebox/JBoss logger from (for example) a scheduled job?

If I do

```
@logger = TorqueBox::Logger.new()
@logger.debug "hello"
```

... it goes nowhere.  I've also tried `TorqueBox::Logger.new("my_rails_app_name")` with the same result.

Comment: Do you have access to the Rails.logger object in your job? Does @logger.info do anything different?

Comment: I can confirm Rails.logger does this for me in a service with TB 3.0